# how to remove php extension from the files in root

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hello i want to convert php urls into SEO urls every thing is  working fine at my end but the files in the root doesn't work here is the code which i am using in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ show_staff.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ show_staff.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ show_users.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ show_users.php?url=$1
```

but if i add these lines right after the above lines the files which are in root doenst work without .php extention here is what i want to add here i want to mention without or with using below code the above code works fine for me

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
```

Comment: No idea how the above code can work fine if both "show_staff" and "show_users" have the **exact same regex pattern**.

Comment: show_users is not important i am planning to remove it but need to fix the bottom code to remove .php extension

Comment: Your final `RewriteCond` do nothing without `RewriteRule`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)$ show_staff.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your stuff is all in the wrong order. Some things:

1. If you don't have an `L` flag for a rewrite, the rules after will continue to process *the rewritten request*. So you want to use the `L` flag.
2. Rewrite conditions *only apply to the immediately following rule*, so you've got a condition that's just dangling somewhere and not being used.
3. The show_users.php rules will never work the way you've set things up, the regex pattern is the same, so **no matter what**, your requests will always go to show_staff.php.
4. Your rules aren't in the right order, two things need to happen if I'm guessing what you're trying to do. You need to match against a request with a php extension and externally redirect the browser, then you need to internally rewrite that request *back* to the URI with a php extension.

So something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^/]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
ReweriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ show_staff.php?url=$1 [L]
```